# iOS 5 iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app is crashing on iOS 5, but I have no idea what's causing this. All my devices are updated to iOS 6 (I cannot downgrade) and the issue is on iPad 1 which cannot be updated to iOS 6.

I am wondering if there's a way I can use the simulator with iOS 5 to test/debug this? Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: You can debug the device while plugged into the Xcode debugger.

Comment: @HotLicks : He doesn't own a device with iOS 5

Comment: crash may occur because of "Use Autolayout" option on xib by the way, you may want to look after it

Comment: This points out the hazards of developing for devices you don't own - caveat developer

Comment: @KevinDTimm : not everyone can afford having many devices with many previous OS versions, and you don't want to restrict your user target just for that reason :)

Comment: @rdurand - calculated risk, there's a price to pay for this economy

Comment: @rdurand And most people can't afford a huge number of 1-star reviews because they didn't bother testing their app across all versions of iOS that their app claims to support. Kevin is simply making a good point about testing.

Comment: @KevinDTimm You really expect an indie dev to own 10 * 3 = 30 devices?!?! (10 devices with 3 version of iOS since you can't downgrade)...and that's atleast 30 devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the cost of doing business - if you say it works on device X/operating system Y, you better be able to test it.  Otherwise, as said above, you get a boatload of 1 star reviews - which is more expensive?

Comment: @0xSina Why 30 devices? You don't need every version on every iOS device. That's silly. One device per iOS version is enough to at least verify you aren't using newer APIs on older versions.

Comment: @rmaddy not sure if I understand. I cannot downgrade to a lower iOS version once I upgrade. There's atleast 10 devices and support is iOS 4.0 +.

Comment: @rmaddy : I agree, I myself test on every versions I claim my app supports, on simulator or with beta testers. Note that my comment was by no mean negative. I totally agree with the points stated here. I believe working on a simulator for previous iOS versions is still better than nothing :)

Comment: @0xSina If you are using Xcode 4.5 then you only can support 4.3 or later. Personally, I abandoned 4.x a while ago. There's so little point to support that far back any more. And again, you don't need every device to test a given version of iOS.

Comment: @rdurand Agreed, testing with the older simulators is better than no testing as long as the tester is fully aware of the limitation of the simulator.

Comment: @rmaddy I know I don't need every device to test a given version of iOS - But that's what KevinDTimm suggested so I told him that's not practical as you'll need alot of devices.

Comment: @rmaddy : +1 for dropping 4.x.. I like using storyboards, and it would be crazy handling nibs & storyboards and maintaining both.. iOS has a great update acceptance by the users, so iOS 5+ is not so restrictive. Also, I can't agree more on the different behaviors between the simulator and a device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you probably can (it's possible that the problem only appears on a device, not in the simulator).

To download the iOS 5 simulator (iPhone & iPad), go to the settings in Xcode, in the "Downloads" section, and install iOS 5.0 and/or iOS 5.1 simulators. Then select the appropriate simulator on the upper left corner of the main window of Xcode before running your app. Also make sure the deployment target of your app is set to iOS 5.0 (first item on the list of the left panel in the main window, select your target and in the "Summary" tab, set your deployment target).

Comment: Since the app is crashing on a device with iOS 5, the app's deployment target must already be 5.x (or 4.3).

Comment: What if the deployment target is iOS 5.1 and he tries running it under iOS 5.0 ?

Comment: If the deployment target is 5.1 then the app wouldn't install on a device with 5.0.

Comment: I know, but he may also want to test/debug on iOS 5.0

Comment: Thanks, doing that right now. Hopefully I can get this bug crashed.

Comment: @0xSina : And if you manage to get more details on the crash, don't hesitate to open a new thread to get help !